# C# using WebBrowser control and need to access DOM elements

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, dom

I have a webpage loading inside my WinForm application using C#

I need to programatically type data into specific fields on that page (without using WATIN).

If anyone has any other solution, I am open to it.

The page in question has NO AJAX or JavaScript. They are simple HTML data entry forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so using the `Document` property of the `WebBrowser` control :

C# code:

```cs
if (webBrowser1.Document == null) return;
var form = webBrowser1.Document.Forms[0]; //form element
var input = form.Children[0]; //input element
input.SetAttribute("value","input value"); //set the input value
form.InvokeMember("submit"); //submit the form
```

Demo HTML page loaded into the `WebBrowser` Control:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="testInput" value="test"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you set the SetAttribute method, are you setting the value for "testInput"? If so, how does your code reference that input tag?

Comment: @CocoaDev Yes. I reference that tag with form.children[**0**] (The Children array of the `form` element contains all the children that are between `<form></form>`. `testInput` being the first child is the reason for `form.children[**0**]` ).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are loading the web page into a WebBrowser control on your WinForm app, you should be able to access the document via the WebBrowser.HtmlDocument.DomDocument property. This is an unmanaged reference to the IE DOM for the page through the MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2 interface.

Answer (score 3):

Use  [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to download the page and use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse it.

An example:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    var page = wc.DownloadString(url);

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(page);

    //XPath
    var title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title").InnerText;
    var text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='readInner']")
                  .InnerText;
    //Linq
    var text = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                .Where(n => n.Attributes["id"].Value == "readInner")
                .First()
                .InnerText;
}
```

Comment: That looks really neat, Linq to Objects for querying in the Beta too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the MSHTML.Dll and SHDocVw.dll

I am just paste code that transfre the code from winform to IE browser in which you just click on button data is transfer to web page but controls as same on web page as well on yours Html page

```
private SHDocVw.InternetExplorer TargetIE = null;
        string url;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetTheIEObjectFromSystem);
            SendTextToActiveElementWithSubmitOptionSet();
        }
        private void GetTheIEObjectFromSystem(
        {
            SHDocVw.ShellWindows SWs = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
            foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer internetExplorer in SWs)
            {
                url = internetExplorer.LocationURL;
                TargetIE = internetExplorer;
                return;
            }

        }
        private void SendTextToActiveElementWithSubmitOptionSet()
        {
            mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 document = null;
            document = TargetIE.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
            if (!document.activeElement.isTextEdit)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Active element is not a text-input system");
            }
            else
            {
                HTMLInputElement HTMLI;
                HTMLI = document.activeElement as HTMLInputElement;
                var tag = HTMLI.document as mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass;
                mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection hTMLElementCollection = tag.getElementsByTagName("input");
                //for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                {
                    foreach (mshtml.HTMLInputElement el in hTMLElementCollection)
                    {
                        switch (el.id)
                        {
                            case "txtFirstName":
                                el.value = textBox1.Text;
                                break;
                            case "txtLastName":
                                el.value = textBox2.Text;
                                break;
                            case "txtAddress":
                                el.value = textBox3.Text;
                                break;
                            case "txtMobile":
                                el.value = textBox4.Text;
                                break;
                        }                        
                    }
                }


            }
        }
```

You make changes as you want I am sure it works