# Read and Write Dynamic HTML in WinForm

Tags: c#, html, winforms, browser

I am using a WinForm App, in c#, framework 3.5. I have a webBrowser control where I render a Dynamic HTML like this

```
 webBrowser1.DocumentText = 
         @"<html>
           <input type=radio name=group1 value=Milk> Milk<br>
           <input type=radio name=group1 value=Butter> Butter<br> 
           </html>";
```

I write two Option Buttons, where the User will click one or another...

When the user click "OK" I need to read the DocumentText, and realize where Option Button is clicked.

It is possible?

Comment: It's not a perfect match, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12058606/3438854) shows the relevant parts of the API. So, yes, it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.. using the ID or the input object. as In javascript.

> webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ID").GetAttribute("checked")